# Does anyone know how to put a stopwatch before and after training each model to evaluate which one is faster?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, python-module

I have created loan risk prediction python machine learning model for Predict whether borrower will able to pay bank loan or not. My model is working perfectly fine with 78% accuracy. However my professor told me that "
Put a stopwatch before and after training each model to evaluate which one is faster, or even better, hits the trade-off between speed and accuracy the best (we want fast and accurate model). ", But i don't know how to add stopwatch in model. I have searched on internet about this thing i didn't get any information about how to put stopwatch in model. Please let me know if anyone know how to put stopwatch before and after training each model

##My Python Prediction model

```
# Importing the Libraries
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)

# Importimg the dataset and displaying first 10 values 
data = pd.read_csv("credit_train.csv")
data.head(10)

# Find null values
data.isnull().sum()

# Drop null records
data = data.dropna(axis=0)

#To get basic information and statistics
data.describe()

# Check number of unique values
data["Home Ownership"].unique()
data["Home Ownership"].value_counts()

# Data Representation
sns.FacetGrid(data,hue="Loan Status",size=4) \
.map(plt.scatter,"Current Loan Amount","Monthly Debt") \
.add_legend()
plt.show()

# Categorical attributes visualization
sns.countplot(x="Loan Status",data=data)
sns.countplot(x="Term",data=data)
sns.countplot(x="Years in current job",data=data)
sns.countplot(x="Home Ownership",data=data)
sns.countplot(x="Loan Status",hue="Home Ownership",data=data)
sns.countplot(x="Loan Status",hue="Term",data=data)

# Numerical attributes visualization
sns.distplot(data['Current Loan Amount'])
sns.distplot(data['Annual Income'])
sns.distplot(data['Credit Score'])
sns.distplot(data['Monthly Debt'])
sns.distplot(data['Current Credit Balance'])

#Normalization and log transformation 
data['Current Loan Amount Log'] = np.log(data['Current Loan Amount']+1)
sns.distplot(data["Current Loan Amount Log"])
data['Credit Score Log'] = np.log(data['Credit Score']+1)
sns.distplot(data["Credit Score Log"])
data['Annual Income Log'] = np.log(data['Annual Income']+1)
sns.distplot(data["Annual Income Log"])
data['Monthly Debt Log'] = np.log(data['Monthly Debt']+1)
sns.distplot(data["Monthly Debt Log"])
data['Current Credit Balance Log'] = np.log(data['Current Credit Balance']+1)
sns.distplot(data["Current Credit Balance Log"])

# Drop unnecessary columns
data = data.drop(['Loan ID', 'Customer ID', "Current Loan Amount", "Credit Score", "Annual Income", 'Years in current job', 'Current Credit Balance', 'Purpose', 'Monthly Debt'], axis=1)

# Correlation Matrix of the columns given below
cols = ['Credit Score Log','Annual Income Log','Monthly Debt Log',
        'Current Credit Balance Log','Current Credit Balance Log','Current Loan Amount Log','Tax Liens','Years of Credit History', 'Maximum Open Credit']
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
cm = np.corrcoef(df.values.T)
sns.set(font_scale=1.5)
hm = sns.heatmap(cm, cbar=True, annot=True, square=True, fmt='.2f', annot_kws={'size': 15}, yticklabels=cols, xticklabels=cols)
plt.show()

# Label Encoding
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
cols = ['Loan Status',"Term","Home Ownership"]
le = LabelEncoder()
for col in cols:
    data[col] = le.fit_transform(data[col])

# data slicing
x = data.drop(columns=['Loan Status'], axis=1)
y = data['Loan Status']

# Train-Test Split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

# Random forest model
# Importing libraries and classes
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(x_train,y_train)

# Find accuracy in training and testing model
model.score(x_train,y_train)
model.score(x_test,y_test)

# Predict the value of test dataset
predicted = model.predict(x_test)

# Generating Report
from sklearn import metrics
print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, predicted))

# Confusion Matrix
print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, predicted))
```

Comment: See this answer I gave someone recently about timing their methods. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67006419/12545290

Comment: use time module https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html?highlight=time#module-time

Comment: @carperyeltsin There is *no* reason for that comment. Bram's comment is autogenerated when someone votes to close your question as a duplicate. It's merely a suggestion that your question has already been answered elsewhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
from time import time

t_bef = time()
function()
t_aft = time()

print("function took", t_aft-t_bef, "seconds")                # stmt1
print("function took", (t_aft-t_bef)*1000, "microseconds")    # stmt2
```

You can replicate a timer by reading the time right before and after the code in the context, by using `time.time()` function. Notice that the time calculation might need to be altered as done in `stmt2` to get precision.

Comment: This is not an accurate way to time code. Use the `timeit` module.

Comment: Yes, it might not preform with accuracy. But it is the most basic it can get.